# How to delete bad entries in Mail's helpful drop-down lists?

Tags: mail.app

When I send an email, I type two or three letters and select the recipient's full name in the list that pops up.  A great feature.  But one day I mistyped an email address and now have several junk entries in that list.  How do I delete those?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go ahead and complete that "bad" name, then click on the downward arrow to the right of the address.

[image]

You can also use the Previous Recipients window to clean things systematically rather than on demand when you are composing and seeing the ones you wish to prune. Once that is complete, check your contacts to make sure the bad address is not stored as a legitimate contact.

Comment: Beautifully neat and simple!  Fairly new to Mac, I just hadn't realized that the '>' meant anything.

Comment: You'll go far in the mac when you notice the smallest of things and ask yourself - "I wonder why they put that there...." The hints are subtle, sometimes invisible.

Comment: Where is the "Previous Recipients" Window?

Comment: @BettyNeal It depends which build of Mail. I use the help menu to locate it since that always knows where to find it.